# How do you find time to conduct deep work weekly as a senior academic?

Tags: research-process, time-management

As seniority increases, admin tasks increase, and effective time for research decreases. There's no way around investing long hours in replying to e-mails, filling up budget forms, and screening/interviewing prospective lab members. Assuming there's no additional staff to help, this can take almost a large fraction of the week, in random slots.

Do you have habits that work successfully to conduct research i.e. "deep work", during long hours e.g. papers/theory/programming every week without interruptions, for at least 3-4 hours? What I care about is a strategy to get research done weekly and consistently, and notice when having many weeks without active research conducted.

I have considered blocking on a fixed weekday the same morning or afternoon slot for this purpose. Alternatively, having a limited slot for replying to e-mails no longer than one hour. This has limitations e.g. urgent meetings/emails that need to be replied to.

Thank you,

[Examples of strategies for deep work (*Medium*).](https://medium.com/@rishisidhu/3-simple-steps-towards-deep-work-c0db9ab606a3)

Comment: My "joke" answer would be to become a mathematician. And if you are a bit of a curmudgeon, you won't be welcome in meetings. I think this is field dependent, actually.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/89362/17254

Comment: Reading these type of questions and answers, I wonder why anyone wants become PI. Actually why? It sounds really depressing to me.

Comment: @tom Simple, at some point you realize you want something done and this something is bigger than yourself. So instead of taking joy in raw, unhindered, first-hand scientific discovery you end up pursuing a distant, bigger dream. It is not as much as people want being PIs, more like hitting their limits, which is more or less depressing - some realize they are not the brilliant scientists they've been aspiring to be their whole lives and are better suited for administrative work, some are more capable of both keeping up with research and managing the team.

Comment: @Lodinn but it is worth working out first whether you have the research management ability (or can gain it) for that strategy to realise your goals.  There are some that are well able to keep up their research, but it would take more time and energy to supervise someone else than it would take for them to do the work themselves.  Sometimes goals are better achieved by collaboration rather than by going into research management.  Both are valid approaches, but unfortunately you need to be able to assess your aptitudes correctly, which is not always easy.

Comment: @tom in many countries the only way to get stable employment is to take on management responsibilities.

Answer (score 12):

Well, you *might* have to accept that from a certain point on you become a manager and no longer an active researcher. For instance, managers in industry do not perform the dirty job of directly designing products, but they are the ones who provide the infrastructure and the organization so that other "lower-level" employees can design and manufacture the products. Likewise, a senior academic, in many cases (with exceptions), no longer performs the dirty calculations or the dirty lab work, but provides the group infrastructure, the organization, the experience, and the big picture so that younger colleagues can do the research work. That's why in certain fields the principal investigator is considered worth of autorship even if they don't directly perform the research: without them, there wouldn't simply be any research.

However, with some care, one can still do a bit of research. My technique is the following:

1. **Be organized and efficient.** Setup standard workflows for your bureaucratical tasks, and allot specific weekly times for some of these tasks (e.g. reply to students only twice a week at certain times, or only when you want to take a break from more demanding tasks). This seems something you already thought of, but relax your expectations on urgent stuff.
2. **Train yourself to switch rapidly between different tasks.** For instance, if when I was a PhD student I could work for hours on a single task, nowadays I'm only able to dedicate 10-20 min to each task, and I've learnt to switch quickly from one task to another, even if they require concentration.
3. **Use idle time to perform background work.** For instance, I usually conceive lectures and classes in my mind while driving to work, while shopping or while having a walk. I also use these idle times to organize papers, so that when I arrive at work I just have to write what I thought.

But, in any case, forget to have 3-4 hours uninterrupted...

Comment: Good PIs, I suspect, also become "idea factories" pumping out ideas for others (especially doctoral students) to actually follow up on. Their insights might also help prevent students from following unproductive lines of inquiry.

Comment: @Buffy Yep, I was considering that under providing experience and big picture ;-)

Comment: +1 The problem is that you tend to get promoted by being good at research to a level where you become a research manager.  Unfortunately being a good researcher does not mean you will be a good research manager - the "Peter Principle" in action.  It is worth asking yourself whether you actually ***want*** to be promoted to that level - is it worth the extra money?  Unfortunately some institutions are not happy with excellent researchers who don't want to be research managers (it may be that they are primarily interested in grants ;o).

Comment: Also you can be an "ideas factory" and provide insights from experience without being a research manager, just by being collegial.

Answer (score 6):

Massimo's answer is great, but also optimistic: For a lot of us at the more senior end of things (I'm 49 and been a full professor for 10 years now), all good intentions often don't lead to much concerted research time. I've tried to block off my Tuesdays for work at home, uninterrupted by meetings. But in practice, I spend most of most Tuesdays preparing for classes, answering emails, having meetings that simply didn't fit anywhere else, even though I've generally been able to at least work from home.

So one, not completely unreasonable, answer to your original question is: There is no magic incantation; a lot of us don't find that uninterrupted deep work on a regular basis. For me, it is a rare day when I get to work on something for 2 or 3 hours at a time; that happens once or twice a month. I just need to work within these constraints and focus on the tasks that I can do within the constraints of my schedule, and that is often doing the writing on papers, rather than the underlying work.

Comment: Do you get interrupted on weekends also?

Comment: @Lodinn For most people there comes a point in their career where "I do my management and advisory job during the day and I do groundbreaking research on evenings and weekends" is simply not doable anymore. Energy and other commitments (family, hobbies) do not allow it.

Comment: @xLeitix ''hobbies''  Then drop the hobbies if they are using time which you need for research.  Sorry.  If you have to make sacrifices then do it.

Comment: @xLeitix I know it is not sustainable for me in the long run, either, and not taking breaks just leads to burnout eventually. But I wanted to know if not having 2-3 hours of time at all is conditional on maintaining the work-life balance or are people later in their careers even more screwed than that and there's no room even for sacrificing "free time" even on a non-regular basis.

Comment: @Tom no, don't do it, you will burn yourself out and be replaced by the next exploitably ambitious academic fresh off the production line (your institution will probably not be grateful).  Overwork is not a way of producing good quality research in the long run.  I know this from personal experience.

Comment: @Tom So academics should save hobbies for retirement? That's a silly opinion. Sorry.

Comment: I decided towards the end of my time as an Assistant Prof that I was burnt out and needed a day off work per week. So Saturday I no longer work, and I manage to do that pretty consistently and not feel bad about it. That's the time for cycling, hiking, and climbing. Sunday is a half-day of work at most. I would be in mentally much worse shape if I worked 7 days a week, and I suspect I would not be more productive either.

Answer (score 0):

Get an assistant if you can. Offload admin tasks onto them.

Otherwise, create set hours for stuff and/or use dead time to multitask those tasks that can be.

Answer (score -6):

Do you work on the weekends?  I work 7 days a week so that I know that I always have two days undistracted where no-one else is around.

Reminds me of when Steven Weinberg was asked how he did so much whilst also teaching, writing books and having a wife and family.  He answered 'I don't ski and I don't go to church', or something like that.  His wife also stated that he just did nothing about from work and had no real hobbies to speak of.

You could perhaps sit down and honestly see how much time you are losing which you don't need to lose, like spending it on phone conversations and stuff like that.  Ultimately, life is about making choices, so if you have to sacrifice something to make way for time to spend on your ambitions, then do it.

Terry Tao also has some [general advice](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice) on his blog which might be useful.

Comment: -1 Steven Weinbergs are vanishingly rare, but the Dikran Marsupials of the academic world are practically ubiquitous, if you want to follow Weinbergs approach, be aware the odds are heavily against it working over a full career.

Comment: Yes, and when you go into a PhD as a student, the odds are very heavily against you going into an academic career at the end of it.  So what?  Doesn't mean you can't do it because many others have failed.

Comment: It's not fair to tell people ''don't try this type of thing, I tried it and it didn't work for me and most people are like me''.

Comment: Your logic is faulty.  If you get a PhD and you actually *want* to be an academic, then the odds are not "heavily" against you.  Also nobody said that you can't do something, just that it is unlikely to work.  Having very few successes where many others have failed is a pretty good definition of the "odds are heavily against it", at least if you are a frequentist.

Comment: I have been an academic for over 25 years, it isn't just my experience, I have seen what has happened to colleagues and friends as well.  None of them were Weinbergs, the really successful ones all had hobbies and lives.  It is perfectly fair to warn readers when bad advice is given, it is kind of why SE has up- and down-votes.  At least I gave an explanation for the down vote.

Comment: I don't want to be too harsh, but according your profile you are still a PhD student. Things tend to look differently once you are 20 years in and have another 20 years of work ahead of you. Even the Tao blog you linked seems to say that working on your research while tired or unmotivated is a bad idea.

Comment: "working on your research while tired or unmotivated is a bad idea."  this is exactly the problem.  If you work when you are tired, it takes longer and the quality suffers.  You also get more tired and risk a downward spiral.  Having time away increases the amount of good research you get done.  Having the odd "sprint" of a couple of weeks is fine, but it shouldn't be standard operating procedure.  It isn't how many hours you work, it is how much progress you make.